# Concurency thread and lock in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, concurrency

I’m wondering how asp.net handle “simultaneous” web requests. Let’s imagine a trading platform where traders can buy stock in real time. Every time a traders send an order, the system has to be sure that only one request can be in the trading thread. This to protect the integrity of the trade. To take an easy example let say, the system need 1 second to execute the order. During this 1 second all the others trade have to wait to be proceed one after another (this can be optimised but let say it is that simple for the sake of the example).

My question is how ASP.net manage concurrency and thread? If I use a lock on a sensitive part of my code, will all request created by asp.net enter the tread one after another?  What is the best way to do that?
How do every threads  created by ASP.net interact with each other to be sure that another one is not already in the sensitive locked part ?

I hope my question make sense, ask me if it’s not clear.

EDIT : I should precise that the orders are send via webservices and that the user is expecting an answer ( success or fail).

Comment: Consider the scenario of a webgarden/webfarm, where there are multiple processes (perhaps on different machines). You will need some other setup than a normal `lock(...) { ... }`, they are not shared between processes/machines. Perhaps writing orders to a queue and have a dedicated "order processing service shazaam" that processes one order at a time? (google: message queueing, nservicebus, msmq, rabbitmq)

Comment: Sounds like you need to read an introductory tutorial on synchronization primitives for multi-threaded programming.  Explaining an entire concept such as synchronization between threads in an answer here is really not feasible.  If you have a more specific question after looking into the topic and attempting a solution then that is generally the more appropriate time to ask a question about it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET really doesn't manage concurrency that much. All it does is accept requests and push them as work items to the thread pool. Eventually, the framework calls into application code.

What your app does, then, is your business. ASP.NET doesn't care. If you want to take a lock and wait, so be it. ASP.NET neither does want to know about that fact nor can it find out if it wanted to. To the system it just looks like your work items are taking quite long (because they are blocking on a lock).

There is no way to tell ASP.NET to call your trading system serially. You have to build that coordination yourself.

As you can see, synchronization inside of ASP.NET is similar to synchronization outside of ASP.NET. (I have glossed over quite a few details.)

Comment: Ok, it seems a bit clearer for me. So if my asp.net controller call a method in another dll, I have to put the lock on this method, right?  Actually it’s what I was thinking intuitively, but I was not sure that several asp.net threads calling the same method in another dll would synchronize well with a lock.

Comment: You got it. The responsibility of synchronization is on you. ASP.NET uses regular threads that behave like they always do.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you need something really fast for trading, forget about ASP.NET and consider client/server with socket. Is with this market usually uses.

I think for your problem you should consider an asynchronous design. Each web request sends the order to a service and this service executes against the market.

This "service" can be an windows service and you can use one of the following alternatives to enqueue all the trades on a single process:

1) ASP.NET sending orders to the service through Socket
2) Database (polling is terrible, but simpler to implement)
3) MSMQ or other implementations (RabbitMQ, Websphere MQ).

Other alternative is to synchronize the threads in the ASP.NET process using locks (take a look at the "lock" reserved word in C#). I don't think it's a good idea to block the ASP.NET thread while waiting for order execution.

Consider HTML5 WebSockets as an alternative too.

But consider your non-functional requirements. Usually this "low-latency" market requires performance.

Comment: I'm not very familiare with the notion of messasing  queue as MSMQ. i will have a look. i'm ok with the idea that each request send the order to a service. but how the service will give back the answer to the user   via the good asp.net thread ?

Comment: The idea with MSMQ is to have a windows service AND the ASP.NET application. For each request in ASP.NET, it puts a message in MSMQ. The service "listens" to the queue (it will receive a callback for each message in the queue, in order). It's an approach. I suggest you evaluate all the alternatives and choose one that best fits your scenario, considering your performance requirements.

Comment: I don't like the idea of having the thread synchronization inside ASP.NET. Usually web apps haves the idea of stateless and short requests (to support load). If you synchronize inside ASP.NET, probably will make the threads block a lot.